# Get office version in addin with office.js

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-js, word-addins

I need to get the office version that is running my word add-in. I need to get some statistics about users.

How could'I get this in Office.js ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported by the APIs. Could you please elaborate on your scenario of why you need it?

Comment: I need to get some statistics about users.